# Initialize Quartz scheduler with Spring 4/Boot

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-boot, spring-4

I have a *Spring 4* application with *Spring Boot* -

There is no **WEBINF/web.xml** file, however, I'd like to initialize a [Quartz 2.2.1 scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/quick-start) on application startup. However, all the examples using [QuartzInitializerServlet](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerServlet.html) define the settings in the **web.xml** file.

Can I add these configurations to my application startup configuration?

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
        @Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/...");
    ds.setUsername("...");
    ds.setPassword("...!");
    return ds;
}
    /** Add configuration to start Quartz here so 
        I can access it throughout the app? **/ 

@Bean
public org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean SchedulerFactoryBean(){
    SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    scheduler.setAutoStartup(true);
    scheduler.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return scheduler;

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Update**

Figured out the spring-framework quartz bean, now I need to correctly implement the datastore to restore jobs in-between runs.

I'm using postgresql + spring-data & hibernate. This configuration reinitializes the database on each run. HSQL reinitializes some 'import.sql' data as well. Should I create a hibernate interface so that the jobs will be restored on testing?

Comment: You mention HSQL at the end, but your `DataSource` is PostgreSQL. If it is PostgreSQL then the default setting for `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is `none` and the JPA tables will not be created or initialized at startup, so I'm a bit confused. You don't need a `DataSource` bean by the way if you just set the `spring.datasource.*` properties in your [external configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/docs/howto.md#configure-a-datasource).

Comment: Have you tried seeing the `@PostConstruct` annotation.. ?

Comment: @DaveSyer yes, I added `hsqldb` to my pom which turned on the `ddl-auto` setting without thinking about it. Should I expect that quartz will be capable of generating it's own job store table like `ddl-auto` or do I have to manually define it? If so I just can't find the schema. I'll change the config to use the preferred spring data way. @user2339071 if I add the @PostContruct I don't assume it will change when Quartz attempts to connect to the database will it?

Comment: If your data source is not hsqldb then the default value for ddl-auto should be 'none'. If it isn't maybe you have an old version of boot? In any case you can switch it to 'none' manually. On the subject of quartz job tables, I have no idea, but I never saw anyone explicitly configure the schema so I assume it creates it automatically.