# Using Quartz with Spring Boot - injection order changes based upon return type of method

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-boot

I am trying to get Quartz working with Spring Boot, and am not managing to get the injection working correctly. I am basing myself on the example shown [here](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/configuring-quartz-with-jdbcjobstore-in.html)

Here is my boot class:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyApp {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public JobFactory jobFactory() {
        return new SpringBeanJobFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean quartz() {
        final SchedulerFactoryBean bean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        bean.setJobFactory(jobFactory());
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        bean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("quartz.properties"));
        ...
        return bean;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

When the `quartz()` method is invoked by Spring, `dataSource` is `null`. However, if I change the return type of the `quartz()` method to `Object`, `dataSource` is correctly injected with the datasource created by reading `application.properties`, the bean is built, everything works and I get a subsequent error saying that Quartz has been unable to retrieve any jobs from the database, which is normal as I haven't put the schema in place yet.

I have tried adding a `@DependsOn("dataSource")` annotation on the `quartz()` method but that doesn't make any difference.

This class is the only class annotated with `@Configuration`.

Here are my dependencies (I'm using Maven but present them like this for space reasons):

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.0.0.RC4
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.0.0.RC4
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.0.0.RC4
org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1
org.springframework:spring-support:2.0.8
```

And the parent:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.0.0.RC4
```

Finally the content of `quartz.properties`:

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726879/initialize-quartz-scheduler-with-spring-4-boot) question, but that question initialises the datasource in the `@Configuration` class)

Comment: "org.springframework:spring-support:2.0.8"! What's that? Is that the problem? (Maybe you mean "spring-context-support:4.0.2.RELEASE"?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app starts up (with a schema error, which is expected) if I use "org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.0.2.RELEASE" ("org.springframework:spring-support:2.0.8" if it ever existed must be nearly 10 years old now and certainly isn't compatible with Boot or Quartz 2).

Comment: I got it here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-support/2.0.8 - it's obviously the wrong thing - my fault for blindly following the latest version  of the first dependency that provided SchedulerFactoryBean...I will accept this answer as soon as I have been able to verify with Spring Context Support 4.0.2.